# How to apply style for Ext js xtype tabpanel using style property?

Tags: javascript, css, json, extjs

I want to change style for `Ext.tab.Panle` element by writing inline css structure as like the following `xtype : button` element

```
{
   xtype: "button",
   itemId: "imageUploadButton1",
   text: "Uploader",
   style: {
      background : '#C81820'
   }
}
```

I want to change the style of tab-panel's header by writing css like this in a Json format. Is it possible?

Following is my tabpanel elemental structure:

```
    {
        xtype:"tabpanel",
        activeTab:0,
        items:[{
            xtype:"panel",
            title:"SHOPABLE IMAGES",
        },{
            xtype:"panel",
            title:"LAYOUT SETTINGS"
        },{
            xtype:"panel",
            title:"HOTSPOT SETTINGS"
        }]
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab headers are instances of [`Ext.tab.Tab`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tab.Tab), which are created dynamically by the tab panel. You can provide a `tabConfig` configuration on the tab panel's items to customize them, and since they're subclasses of `Ext.Component`, of course you can also set the [`style`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tab.Tab-cfg-style) config:

```
items:[{
    xtype: "panel",
    title: "SHOPABLE IMAGES",
    tabConfig: {
        style: {
            background: '#C81820'
        }
    }
},{
    xtype: "panel",
    title: "LAYOUT SETTINGS"
},{
    xtype: "panel",
    title: "HOTSPOT SETTINGS"
}]
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/o7c